# Is there any way to exploit a floating sand/gravel glitch in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any way to exploit a floating sand/gravel glitch in minecraft? Like lets say you have a solid block like dirt. And then you place a gravel or sand block high above it, and just as it touches the dirt block you destroy it and then the sand/gravel floats?

Has anyone ever done this before? Are there any ways of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than trying to do it in-game, you can use [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-updated-for-mc-beta-165/) to achieve the same effect. In MCedit, select an area of air and use the *Fill & Replace* tool to select sand. Save your world, and voila: floating sand.

[image: Floating sand]

Apparently, sand doesn't start falling until it's interacted with.

There's also a weird interaction between sand and torches, in that sand will float above a torch:

Minecraft physics is the best kind of physics.

Comment: And since water puts out torches (I think, right? Tell me I'm not going crazy!) you can use redstone-activated water to trigger sand cave-in traps. This'll get even easier next patch with pistons.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yup, that's correct. :)

Comment: +1 for `Minecraft physics is the best kind of physics`

Comment: minecraft also generates its own floating sand sometimes

Comment: I once found a naturally occurring waterfall over a pool of lava.  They didn't interact and form obsidian until I interacted with the lava, at that point the entire pool became obsidian.  Not sure how to exploit that though.

Answer (score 0):

if you end off not being able to use/find an external world editor someone on a minecraft server showed me how to do this by using tall grass and putting the sand/gravel ontop of it then break the bottom of the grass and the top wont update the sand/gravel and this way you can do it in survival without cheating